# Inversing limit-integral $\lim_{s\rightarrow0} \int_0^{\infty} \{ u^{s-1} \sin(u) \} du$

Tags: integration, limits, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I thought that a justification of inversing the limit-integral in a [discussion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4wQ_F1s1UI) (moment 5:50) of the integral of the sinc function using the Euler Integral was needed, it inversed the limit integral :

$$ \lim_{s\rightarrow0} \int_0^{\infty} \{ u^{s-1} \sin(u) \} du \qquad \text{getting} \quad \int_0^{\infty} \{ u^{-1} \sin(u) \} du$$

Under my current understanding, if we take $f(s,u) = u^{s-1} sin(u)$ and $\lim_{s\rightarrow 0} f(s,u) = \phi(u) = u^{-1} \sin(u)$ , we need to apply something like dominating it for example $\|f(s,u) \| \leq g(u) $ by an integrable function on it's domain of integration so that we get $ \lim_{s\rightarrow 0}F(s) = \int \phi(u)du$

Is such an application of some result is needed here indeed or did I miss something?

Comment: Integrate by parts or look at $\int_0^\infty (u^{s-1}-(u+\pi)^{s-1})\sin(u)du$ to make it absolutely convergent

Comment: @reuns How do you think integration by parts would help here? knowing that the actual solution for this function when s approaches zero cannot be solved using elementary functions, I also don't understand how to use looking at $\int_0^\infty (u^{s-1}-(u+\pi)^{s-1})\sin(u)du$ for inversing the limit and the integral or for making it absolutely convergent to do so?